# Importing multiple images into premiere, getting the same one multiple times

Tags: premiere, photos, media

I'm trying to import multiple images into premiere which I've prepared and exported in illustrator before. All I'm getting is the same images all over again. Even if I browse the folder through premiere I see them exactly the same. In finder they are fine

[image: screenshot]

If I place them onto the timeline and render in to out, they are also all the same.

Comment: Are you importing via drag & drop, or through file>import? Try using import from the menu (or ctrl/cmd+i), drag and drop is notorious for causing problems.

Comment: Thanks for your response! Tried both...

Answer (score 0):

Solved by using the "Video" mode in Illustrator which you can select while setting up your file after you click "create new"